# How to set clipboard with value of selected cell in Numbers using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to automate a repeating task between Numbers and Quicken 2017 using AppleScript.

I would like to take the contents of the currently selected cell in Numbers, set the clipboard with that numeric value, and paste that value into the search field in Quicken.

How can one go about doing that with AppleScript?

Example pseudo code to illustrate intent:

```
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    set myCellsValue to value of currently selected cell
    set the clipboard to myCellsValue
end tell
tell application "Quicken 2017"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "f" using {command down}
        delay 0.1
        keystroke "v" using {command down}
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You got it 90% correct. I don't use Quicken, but this worked with Microsoft Word:

```
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    tell active sheet to tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using command down
end tell

tell application "Quicken 2017"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "f" using command down
        delay 0.1
        keystroke "v" using command down
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally like to minimise the amount by which I employ *System Events* to issue keystrokes or mouse clicks if there’s another way.

*Numbers* is very much AppleScript-able.  I don’t use it personally, but with the help of [this site](https://iworkautomation.com/numbers), I’ve pieced together this **example** script that I wholly admit is *untested* (I’d appreciate your feedback if you try it out):

```
tell application "Numbers"
    tell the front document to ¬
        tell the active sheet to ¬
            set CurrentTable to the first table whose class of selection range is range

    tell the CurrentTable to get the value of the first cell in the selection range

    if the result is not missing value then set the clipboard to the result
end tell
```

*Quicken* is also AppleScript-able, but I can’t find a downloadable copy of *Quicken*’s AppleScript dictionary in order to piece together an equivalent sample of code.  However, your *Quicken* `tell` block is exactly right for employing *System Events* to issue a <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

However, if you fancy uploading a PDF of the AppleScript dictionary, I can use it to try and draft something more robust.